# TiDB single drainer architecture is creating a single point of failure

Tags: tidb

We’re trying to create Master-Master replication between two TiDB clusters. Each cluster has 3 PD server, 4 KV servers and 2 TiDB server. TiDB is running with binlog enabled. On TiDB servers we have also installed pump.
Now we came to installing drainer and we’re seeing the following issues:

- If we deploy multiple drainers on same TiDB servers configured to sync data to remote TiDB cluster - we’re getting duplicated entries in remote TiDB. Each drainer is sending inserts separately, so for each inserted record on source cluster we get 2 records on destination cluster
- If we deploy single drainer on separate server allocated specifically for it, we’re creating single point of failure. If something happens to this server - data won’t be synced.
  Additionally, we couldn’t find any infromation about design of pump cluster. As we know, pump is saving all transactions for gc days, and minimum what is possible to set is 1 day.
- If we have 2 TiDB servers and each of them is running pump - does each pump saves same full data? Or is it sharded? Does it have replicas if it’s sharded? If we lose one of TiDB servers (with pump running on it) - do we lose part of pump data?

Answer (score 0):

I am a TiDB user too.

From the official website, it recommends you use separate instances to deploy pumps and drainers.

Q1:  Does each pump saves same full data? Or is it shaded?
If you deploy more than 1 pump, the transaction records will be randomly sent to pumps and drainer is for merging those binlogs based on the commit time.

```
Drainer collects and merges binlogs from each Pump, converts the binlog to SQL or data of a specific format, and replicates the data to a specific downstream platform.

https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/tidb-binlog-overview#:~:text=Drainer%20collects%20and%20merges%20binlogs%20from%20each%20Pump%2C%20converts%20the%20binlog%20to%20SQL%20or%20data%20of%20a%20specific%20format%2C%20and%20replicates%20the%20data%20to%20a%20specific%20downstream%20platform.
```

Q2.If we lose one of TiDB servers (with pump running on it) - do we lose part of pump data?
Ideally, if one pump fails, then new binlogs will be sent to other available pumps and binlog files are stored in a drainer machine rather than a pump.

```
Here is the drainer config file: 
https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-binlog/blob/master/cmd/drainer/drainer.toml
```

I think it is very useful, you may follow it to do your own setup.
In my experience, you may store binlogs to two drainers to avoid losing data instead of having one drainer only. Also, the alternative way is to sync binlogs to kafka, which is also available in the `drainer.toml` file.